# saslauthd 0: No authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, ldap, sasl

Here I have attached my saslauthd conf file. ANd When I run the command 
`testsaslauthd -u mongoldap -p coolcomp@123 -f /var/run/saslauthd/mux` 
[image][image]

0:No authentication failed error occurs. 
Please let me know if ther eis any solution to resolve this. Thanks in advance.